# How to integrate Angularjs + Bootstrap + angular.translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-4, angular-translate

Angularjs and Bootstrap are working together in the system without problems I need to implement angular-translate also.

I call the translate archives in the HTML:

```
<script src="js/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate-loader-static-files/2.17.0/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js"></script>
```

Example of use:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <label>{{ 'Hello World' | translate }}</label>
</div>
```

- *the angular-translate.min.js archive is in the correct folder*

In the js document I take the translate parameter:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $element, $compile, $timeout, $translate) {
$translate.use('es');}
```

In the main.js on an onload script is the problem because I don't know if this it's the right way to implement it:

```
script.onload = function () {
    try{
        if (angular) {
            var mainApp = angular.module('myApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

            mainApp.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
                $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
                    prefix: '../translations/translation_',
                    suffix: '.txt'
                });
                $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('es');
                $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape');
                $translateProvider.forceAsyncReload(true);
            }]);

            angular.element(document).ready(function() {
                angular.bootstrap(document, ["myApp"]);
            });
        }
    }catch(err){}
}
```

- *the .txt document has the key 'Hello World' and the correct spanish traduction*

Comment: Can you look at the Network tab in the Browser and make sure that you have at least HTTP requests for getting such files? P.S I copied your configuration to the angular-translate example app and it works fine. I see requests in the Network. https://jsfiddle.net/gtrwzsn1/3098/

Comment: Yes I have requests for getting the tranlation file.

Comment: The error that I have now is this one: 
Error: error:areq Bad Argument
Argument 'myCtrl' is not a function, got undefined